# Codeigniter: Is DX_Auth outdated?

Tags: codeigniter

I tried installing DX_Auth in CI 2.1.0 and it's throwing errors everywhere. I took a look at some of the files and much of it is written for PHP 4. Should I be using a different auth library instead?
Things I noticed:

- Uses `Classname` instead of `__construct`. However, this is easy to change
- DX has a *plugins* folder while CI does not. Is this the equivalent of the *third_party* folder?
- Also, there is no `$this->load->plugin()` which to load the DX *plugin* folder
- Took a look at DX_Auth.php and saw it says (c) 2008. So...it hasn't been updated since 2008?

This is my first time using an Auth library. Should I be using a different library instead of DX_Auth?

Comment: as of **12/30/2013**, *DX_Auth* is a bit outdated.  Look to something else if you are using **CI3.X**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I have stuck to using **Tank Auth** and it is up to date IMHO.
Details are here: http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/

Also changelog etc; here: https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth

Comment: Will be using Tank Auth from now on.

Comment: If you ever want to get into OpenID + oAuth2, etc; have a look at [**HybridAuth**](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) as well for CI

Answer (score 1):

Try ion_auth: http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/

It is updated frequently and works correctly with latest version of CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

Few years back I used DX Auth. It worked great! 
3 months ago, again I had to use authentication library in one of my (Code Igniter) projects. When I searched for DX auth, found very little information. Even I couldn't access their users manual that was well written. After searching for a while, I found the code on github. Now, I've Implemented it with CodeIgniter 3 without any issue. However, I stuck in some places due to lack of documentation. But it's not a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

DX auth is getting a new refraction and upgrading the library, but still it  isn't outdated, you can use the library functionality's without any issues.

Simply modify the Controllers and Models by adding a postfix CI_

[DX Auth](https://github.com/eyoosuf/DX-Auth) is now on GitHub